# Why is the orthogonal group $\operatorname{O}(2n,\mathbb R)$ not the direct product of $\operatorname{SO}(2n, \mathbb R)$ and $\mathbb Z_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, orthogonal-matrices

We know that when $n$ is odd, $\operatorname{O}_n(\mathbb R) \simeq \operatorname{SO}_n (\mathbb R) \times \mathbb Z_2$.

However, this seems **not true when $n$ is even**. But I have no idea how to prove something is not a direct product.

I have tried to verify some basic properties of direct product. For example, $\operatorname{SO}_n(\mathbb R)$ is a normal subgroup of $\operatorname{O}_n(\mathbb R)$, whenever $n$ is odd or even. But they are not helpful.

So, is this statement true and how to prove it?

Thank you!

Comment: $O(2)=\mathbb{Z}/(2)\rtimes SO(2)$. $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$ conjugation is inversion: reflect rotate reflect=rotate inverse.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Look at the centers:  the center of $\operatorname{O}(n)$ is $\pm \operatorname{Id}$.  When $n$ is even, this is also the center of $\operatorname{SO}(n)$.  Therefore for even $n$ the center of $\operatorname{SO}(n) \times \mathbb Z_2$ is $\{\pm \operatorname{Id} \} \times \mathbb Z_2$, which is bigger than the center of $\operatorname{O}(n)$.

EDIT:  This works for $n \ge 3$.  For $n=2$, $\operatorname{O}(2)$ is non-abelian while $\operatorname{SO}(2) \times \mathbb Z_2$ is.

Comment: Typo: "...the center of SO(n)xZ_2 is..." (not SO(n)). Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @gnometorule: thanks, I just edited it.

Answer (score 2):

In this answer, we for fun generalize and write out the construction in more detail.

1. An element in the [orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group)$^1$ $O(n,\mathbb{F})$ has determinant $\pm 1$. The [center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_(group_theory)) is $$Z(O(n,\mathbb{F}))~=~\{\pm \mathbb{1}\}~\cong~\mathbb{Z}_2,\tag{1}$$
   $$Z(SO(n,\mathbb{F}))~=~\left\{\begin{array}{c}\{ \mathbb{1}\}\text{ if $n$ odd},\cr
   \{\pm \mathbb{1}\}\text{ if $n$ even}.\end{array}\right.\tag{2}$$
   Here $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
2. $O(n,\mathbb{F})$ has 2 distinct components
   $$O(n,\mathbb{F})~=~SO(n,\mathbb{F}) ~\sqcup~ P\cdot SO(n,\mathbb{F}),\tag{3}$$
   where $P\in O(n,\mathbb{F})$ is a fixed element with $\det P=-1$.
3. There is always a group isomorphism from the [semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product)
   $$ \mathbb{Z}_2 ~\ltimes~ SO(n,\mathbb{F})~~\stackrel{\Phi}{\cong}~~O(n,\mathbb{F}) \tag{4}$$
   given by 
   $$ ((-1)^p, M)~~\stackrel{\Phi}{\mapsto}~~ P^p\cdot M, \qquad p~\in~\{0,1\},\qquad M~\in~SO(n,\mathbb{F}) . \tag{5}$$
   The factor $(-1)^p$ is the determinant. Explicitly, the semidirect product reads
   $$ ((-1)^{p_1}, M_1)\cdot ((-1)^{p_2}, M_2)~=~((-1)^{p_1+p_2}, P^{-p_2}\cdot M_1\cdot P^{p_2}\cdot M_2). \tag{6}$$
4. On one hand, if we choose the fixed element $P$ to belong to the center (1), the semidirect product (6) becomes a [direct product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups). This is precisely possible if $n$ is odd.
5. On the other hand, for $n$ even, then $O(n,\mathbb{F})$ and the direct product $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times SO(n,\mathbb{F})$ have different centers, so they cannot be isomorphic, cf. answer by Eric O. Korman.

--

$^1$ Here $\mathbb{F}$ is a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) with [characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)) different from 2.